# UItextfield password

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield

I know that its possible to make UITextfield operate in a password mode by using the following :

```
textfield.secureTextEntry = YES;
```

This changes all characters entered by the user into '*'. However, the last character entered flashes up for about half a second. I understand that this is standard behavior.

Is there any way of stopping this and keeping the characters entered completely obscured?

To achieve this, Im thinking of subclassing `UITextField` and then overriding `drawTextInRect:rect`

But I would welcome any other suggestions.

Comment: why haven't you tried to do it before you ask? :)

Comment: Maybe because OP's looking for an easier solution.

Comment: As Dandan said, I was hoping someone on here would have encountered the problem before and maybe suggest an alternative or even a possibly easier solution...

Comment: I think you have to do it on your own way. In my opinion there is no easier solution then the one you thought about in your post.

Comment: Thanks Andy...really just wanted someone to confirm

Comment: Quick Update....The solution I proposed doesn't work...The drawtextInRect method on UITextField is never called when the user enters text..Apparently the "Text" is contained in a UILabel inside the UITextfield....Anyways, as you were...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

- Set the UITextField as regular, not secret.
- Listen to the event `UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification`
- When it happens replace the characters of your textfield for "*" and store the real password in a property.

This code works, it's kind of ugly, though, it can probably be optimized.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector: @selector(keyPressed:) name: UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification object: nil];
}

- (void) keyPressed: (NSNotification *) notification {
    if(!self.password)
        self.password = @"";

    NSString* fieldText = [notification.object valueForKey:@"text"];
    NSString* lastChar = [fieldText substringFromIndex:fieldText.length-1];

    if(self.password.length>fieldText.length)
        self.password = [self.password substringToIndex:self.password.length-1];
    else
        self.password = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", self.password, lastChar];

    NSString* secret = @"";
    for (int l = 0; l<self.password.length; l++) {
        secret = [secret stringByAppendingString:@"*"];
    }
    self.textField.text = secret;
}
```

Comment: cheers for the reply.. Thats almost exactly what I did come up with in the end.