# Completely obscuring password in the UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I know how to set a UITextField to show dots instead of text by setting secureTextEntry to true. But I want to completely obscure the password. Not showing the character even for fractions of seconds.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11898093/uitextfield-password. It's Objective-C but it's the same APIs.

Comment: I am new to iOS programming (learning swift) and never worked on Objective C. I saw this answer but had a hard time understanding it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

it's not the best solution but sort of helps. Basically create a fake field that does nothing visually. but type on the password field hidden and add asterisks on the fake visual one. also gotta listen then it is focused let the hidden field to become first responder.

[image]

```
class MyViewController : UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    var password = ""
    var fakeField = UITextField()
    var passwordField = UITextField()

    override func loadView() {

        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .white

        fakeField.frame = CGRect(x: 150, y: 400, width: 200, height: 20)
        fakeField.placeholder = "Password"

        passwordField.delegate = self

        view.addSubview(fakeField)
        view.addSubview(passwordField)

        passwordField.becomeFirstResponder()
        passwordField.isHidden = false

        self.view = view
    }
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        fakeField.text = "\(fakeField.text ?? "*")*"
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try it and let you know if it works. I need to do it for text field created using a storyboard. I have to update it a little. I will accept it as the answer once it works for me.

Comment: @ManinderSingh did it finally work out? Still available to help you. regards.

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't get time to try it. I will try it soon and let you know. Thanks a lot!